# Error encrypting image using fresh saved image

Tags: c#, image-processing, encryption

first I create image using image.save, here's a snippet code :

```
    private void Save(Bitmap image)
    {
        string fullPath = string.Empty;
        string encryptPath = string.Empty;
        bool isSaved = false;

        try
        {
            // my code                

            image.Save(fullPath, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters); // save and image created

            isSaved = true;

            Log.WriteLine("PictureCapturer", "<< Save", LogLevel.Information, 0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.WriteLine("PictureCapturer", "Error when Save : " + ex, LogLevel.Error, 0);
        }
        finally
        {
            image.Dispose();
        }

        if (Properties.EncryptPicture && isSaved)
        {
            Crypto.EncryptFile(fullPath, encryptPath); // start encrypt file
        }
    }
```

the snippet code for file encryptor using Rijndael :

```
    public void EncryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string password = @"xxxxxxx";
            UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
            byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);

            string cryptFile = outputFile;
            FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(cryptFile, FileMode.Create);

            RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
                RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, key),
                CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open); // ERROR HERE

            int data;
            while ((data = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
                cs.WriteByte((byte)data);

            fsIn.Close();
            cs.Close();
            fsCrypt.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string e = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

but there's an error when encrypt the image :

**Message = "The process cannot access the file 'D:\Foto\xxxxx.Jpeg' because it is being used by another process."**

fyi I wanna create the image and encrypting image in a run time.

thanks for the helps

Comment: On which line do you get the exception?

Comment: FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);

Comment: Do you get this exception on the first run? Are there any other exceptions before it? I see the fileStreams are not closed in the catch

Comment: it's not, if I create image without encrypting it, the image (not encrypted image) created. but when I encrypt the image that just created. the original image broken and i got this error. if I'm not debugging, the error actually appearing in catch.

Answer (score 1):

The message:

"The process cannot access the file 'D:\Foto\xxxxx.Jpeg' because it is being used by another process."

Means that a program opened the file and never `Close`d it. Two things:

1) Make sure that no other programs have the file open (like if you have it open in Explorer or in an image viewer, for example)
2) Make sure that your current or previous iterations of the program didn't open the file and never close it. For example, your program does not `Close` the file if an exception is thrown. I recommend using `finally` blocks for cleaning up resources, such as calling `Close` and `Dispose`, because `finally` blocks are always executed after all the code ends, wheter an exception was thrown, caught, whatever.

Comment: hi.. I adding the full source code, i already using try catch and using dispose but the error still appearing

Comment: @Opik Taufik Maybe you need to use finally and close in EncryptFile?

Comment: Hi.. it doesn't matter because the error is on EncryptFile itself, I think the problem is when I create FileStream using the original image, the original image still "stuck" somewhere..